# How to import users' encrypted passwords from a legacy application to a new application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

As devise uses bcrypt for password encryption, it should be possible to import users and their passwords into a new application with the change being seamless to the end user.

However, any import procedure via CSV, or even a console command to create, using the `encrypted_password` field  will fail, as devise expects `password` and password_confirmation`.

How can this condition be over-ridden for a CSV import process?

Comment: would need to import the password directly into the database -- you would also need to use the same secret_key in the devise configuration

Comment: how could I import that? it seems the process is impeded by Devise, it wants `password` and `password_confirmation`.  the import via CSV process does not import as it fails this Devise validation

Comment: Whatever database you are using should have a bulk import capability to take data directly from from a CSV file and populate the users table directly.

Answer (score 0):

@dbugger's comments are correct.  Devise is bypassed by loading directly into the database.  A [good, succinct example is provided here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/import-csv-file-into-posgresql-table/)  for postgresql.

One gotcha however.  Although strings can be input blank into the csv file for uploading

```
[...] ,valentina.takesabus@gmail.com,[...]
```

the `encrypted_password` needs quotes

```
[...] "$2a$10$3yiD1NGkF9sCCmntNJEpce11OJtnx568sX0NM9kPCq.WIOoGX3Ko."  [...]
```

otherwise they would not load properly and has errors ensue.